# calabash-android rotation: how to rotate in calabash-android v0.5

Tags: android, ruby, automated-tests, calabash

How does one rotate the screen using `v0.5` of `Calabash-Android`? since the pre-defined steps of rotation, previously contained in the `rotation.rb` file have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share the command for changing the orientation of the device to the desired *portrait* or *landscape*:

`perform_action('set_activity_orientation', 'portrait')`

`perform_action('set_activity_orientation', 'landscape')`

Credit: [Balazs Balazs](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/calabash-android/1448cyga18/i-rotate-device-left%7Cright). This is the [original thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/calabash-android/1443yps722/i-rotate-device-left%7Cright).